# Crash when adding and removing entities in Qt3D

Tags: qt, qt3d

I have entities that should be created and deleted at runtime. Entity have only material and mesh component. Material is QDiffuseMapMaterial with QTextureImage.

When entities begin to add and delete from scene, sometimes application crashes with this assert:

> qt_assert: ASSERT: "img != nullptr" in file
>   ../../include/Qt3DRender/5.8.0/Qt3DRender/private/../../../../../src/render/texture/apitexturemanager_p.h,
>   line 286

But unfortunately I can’t figure out why it happenes. I’m adding the entity this way:

```
QEntity * visibleObject = new QEntity();

QDiffuseMapMaterial * material = new QDiffuseMapMaterial();

QTextureImage * diffuseTextureImage = new QTextureImage();
diffuseTextureImage->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/resources/tile.png"));
material->diffuse()->addTextureImage(diffuseTextureImage);
visibleObject->addComponent(material);

// set mesh
QPlaneMesh * mesh = new QPlaneMesh();
mesh->setWidth(1.0 / 2);
mesh->setHeight(1.0 / 2);
visibleObject->addComponent(mesh);

visibleObject->setParent(_rootEntity);
```

And delete just like this:

```
delete visibleObject;
```

`_rootEntity` is scene root entity defined in cpp code. Scene defined in QML file using Scene3D:

```
 Scene3D {
     id: scene
     anchors.fill: parent
     aspects: ["render", "logic", "input"]

     entity: rootEntity
 }
```

And `_rootEntity` passed like this:

`context->setContextProperty("rootEntity", _rootEntity);`

If it is necessary I can prepare simple example that reproduce issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The line `visibleObject->setParent(_rootEntity);` means that _`rootEntity` takes ownership of `visibleObject`. If you `delete visibleObject;` you create a dangling pointer in _`rootEntity`. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html. So don't `delete visibleObject;`

Comment: I've already tried to delete it like this: `visibleObject->setParent(nullptr); delete visibleObject;` but the behavior is the same. Anyway it seems that it is Qt bug (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59418).

Answer (score 0):

It seems your trouble is that you've defining how to delete things incorrectly, The best solution to any problem is to eliminate the problem entirely.

Have you attempted to use smart pointers? Specifically Shared pointers? Using smart pointers eliminates the issue of hanging references entirely, and there is little if any overhead associated with their use. Qt even has it's own dedicated implementation of smart pointers.

If you eliminate the necessity to explicitly specify the deletion of your objects, you wouldn't have issues specifying the deletion.